# Install two separate internet connection in my home

Tags: networking, internet

I run a business out of my home on my current internet connection which my kids are using as well. My business network needs to be separate from what my kids are doing.

Is it possible to install a second internet connection in my home that my two teenagers can use?

Comment: This is going to depend on your provider and whether there are any other providers serving your area - for example, I can use the local telephone utility's fiberoptic service for one connection, and the local cable provider for a second - but neither would offer a second connection to my premeses unless they're specifically zoned for business.

Comment: Maybe. This depends on where you live. Probably best to call some internet service providers in your local area and ask around. They can answer that question much better than we can.

Comment: I wonder if this is an XY question.  Do you need 2 connections or do you need to seperate the ability for home users to interfere with business ones?  If the latter, what threats are you trying to mitigate ?

Comment: Voting to close because this can only really be answered by the original poster’s ISP. If they will allow a second, completely independent connection come into their home, that is just the case of setting up a second account. But it might not be a policy issue as much as a capacity and wiring issue. For example, if a fairly large and well populated area this should not be an issue. And ditto for many suburbs. But if the location is rural there might be issues with the ISP running a new line. Again, it all depends on the ISP. Nobody here can answer this better than they can.

Comment: If the question is "how many isps service my area", likely more then 1 if you include Starlink. (Also, it should be possible for 1 ISP to provide more then 1 connection to an address)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of-course it is.  There are many ways to do this depending on your needs and goals.

The simplest is to just get 2 connections with 2 routers.  The only things you need to do then is give the routers different SSIDS (wifi ap names), and you will ideally want to ensure non-overlapping channels. It likely makes sense to try have the routers seperated by at least a few meters to help the wifi work better.This is a simple solution that will *just work* but does not maximise wifi performance.

As a refinement, if practical, connect the business connection via ethernet and disable WIFI altogether on it (assuming you only need the business Internet connection devices you can practically connect to ethernet.  This is more secure and will allow for faster wifi on the home connection.

There are other, way more complex solutions but these will require specialist knowledge and likely depend on your exact goals and require specialist hardware.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

You can call your (or any other available) ISP to get a second internet connection (wired or mobile whatever is available).

**But:** you don't need a second one if your main concern is to keep your work devices separated from your kid's devices. There are plenty of consumer routers that can separate networks from each other (e.g. the main network for you and your work and the guest network for your kids). In some routers, there's also the option to set a limit on the down-/upload rates as well (so your kids don't use up too much of your data line leaving you with a bad connection). This way you'll still be able to share one internet connection while meeting all the requirements for your work.

There is another issue though: if you have a second internet connection for private use you have a backup in case your work internet connection fails. That might be something worth considering.